# Regex for swap info in AIX mahine

Tags: regex, linux, aix

swap info command in AIX : `lsps -a`

swap info output in AIX :

```
Page Space      Physical Volume   Volume Group    Size %Used Active  Auto  Type
paging00        hdisk1            rootvg        5120MB    63   yes   yes    lv
hd6             hdisk1            rootvg        4992MB    65   yes   yes    lv
```

How can i get the `Size` and `%Used` values?

something like

```
5120MB    63
4992MB    65
```

**Updated**
Here is what i did

```
lsps -a | awk '{print $4" "$5}'
```

which gets me

```
Volume Volume
5120MB 63
4992MB 65
```

I don't want the 1st line `Volume Volume`. I might do `lsps -a | awk '{print $4" "$5}'|tail -2` but there can be more than 2 rows :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awklette should do it.

```
lsps -a | awk '$1 != "Page"  { print $4 " " $5 }'
```

You can achieve the same thing with "cut" or "sed" but Ive alway found awk more readable and reliable.

*In response to comment requesting resources:*

A collection of nifty one liners is found here [here](http://awk.info/?awk1line)

And some more in depth documentation is [here](http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/awk.shtml)

and a good tutorial is [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Comment: Anderson: Wow! Thanks, awk is really good solved my problem, can you suggest me some place to learn `awk` something like your answer?

Answer (score 0):

This line should do what you need:

```
lsps -a | grep -oi '[0-9]+[a-z]+[ \t]+[0-9]+'
```

Comment: It gives me `% lsps -a | grep -oi '[0-9]+[a-z]+[ \t]+[0-9]+'
grep: Not a recognized flag: o`